# I want to create a Megamenu that combines flyout and dropdown features

Tags: css, wordpress, nav, megamenu

I am trying to create a megamenu for our website at great-news.ca
We publish 61 newsletter and service 110 communities in our city.
This means.... a LOT OF ITEMS...which need to be organized as cleanly as possible.

I am not sure if I know how to describe what I want ... but  here we go:

I need to create a nav menu, that lists the main categories on top, with a vertical dropdown menu, which can list all of its sub item lists with in a large container as a flyout option...

IE for the newsletter section:

Navbar

NEWSLETTERS »    COMMUNITIES »    SERVICES »     ABOUT 
                        SE Newsletter
                        SW Newsletter
 
                        NE Newsletter
submenu}        NW Newsletter      » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4
                                                     » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4  
                                                     » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4  
                                                     » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4  
                                                     » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4  
...............................li item.....>      » COLUMN 1      COLUMN 2      COLUMN 3      COLUMN 4

*not sure if this will display properly 

Here is list a of examples that combine both elements.

godaddy com/  (under the products tab)

callawaygolf com (golf equiment/golf clubs)

They do exactly what I want....

Note that I don't want to have all of the newsletter items inside a big container box... but instead I want a vertical dropdown menu that has a flyout container box with the specific items for that category.

so even though starbucks com and www.microsoft com are great examples for megamenus, is NOT WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE.... I REALLY DON'T want a huge container where all the the category and subitems are mixed, but instead they are neatly organized and hidden,, ready to be called out of the dropdown menu items.

I am currently using wordpress 3.7 to build the site, and did purchase a plug-in called ubermenu, http://wpmegamenu.com/,  that does something similar to the starbucks and microsoft sites... but its not what i want,

Any help?

Comment: maybe some wordpress tags...

Comment: Hire a developer then.  This is just a work order, not a Stack Overflow question.